# Why must we type vim ~/.vimrc and why not just vim ~.vimrc?

Tags: vim, terminal

I know that the latter doesn't work and that the former is the correct one, but is there a syntactic matter that renders the second method wrong?

cd ~ brings me to my home directory, so why doesn't vim ~.vimrc work?
Why is there a need for a "/"?

Comment: This is off-topic, but why would you *not* need a slash? If you have a directory called "foo" that contains a file called "bar.txt", would you expect that "vim foobar.txt" works?

Comment: it's not in a directory, Juhana.

Comment: Your home directory is not a directory?

Comment: my .vimrc file isn't in a directory

Comment: It is in your home, and your home is a directory.

Comment: @romainl of course I know my home is a directory... = =;

Comment: Also `cd ~` doesn't bring me to the root but to my home directory.

Comment: You want to access the .vimrc in your home directory. And therefore you need the slash to make sure, that you are talking about the .vimrc file within your home directory. Otherwise, it is unclear, to what ~.vimrc should refer to. BTW: this is general Unix behaviour, you might want to read a book about Shells and look for Tilde Expansion [See POSIX here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_01)

Answer (score 11):

Because `~foo` is expanded by your shell before Vim gets to see it, and your shell expands `~foo` to the home directory of user `foo`.  In particular, `~` is just a shortcut for `~<yourusername>`.  These are shell conventions, they don't have anything to do with Vim.

Comment: I think the question was not about 'vim', it was about finding a rational reason for the choice of this convention. Is it "just" a choice or is there and advantage to it ?

Comment: @Mathiou Then the question makes even less sense.  Some 40 years ago the native OS on PDP-11 machines was CP/M, which was a kind of primitive MS-DOS.  UNIX was an attempt to implement an useful operating system on PDP-11, and it started as a (brutally) stripped down MULTICS.  In particular the concept of shell was inherited from MULTICS.  To understand why `~foo` made more sense as "home directory of `foo`" then "`foo` in my home" on MULTICS, you'd have to get familiar with the circle of ideas of MULTICS.  Good luck doing that in 2015.

Comment: @geoyws You earned a downvote from me for not taking your time to understand the relation between the shell and everything else.  It's really a basic concept.  Can't comment on other people's reasons for downvotes.

Comment: There are other people who can benefit from this question, but since you're not interested in our learning, then I suppose you can keep down-voting. You didn't recommend readings and whatever you said has no substantiation whatsoever. What makes you think you're an authority on this matter?

Comment: I cancelled your answer. No substantiation.

Comment: @geoyws Like other people, I offered an answer, the way I saw it, without claiming to be an authority on anything.  Like other posters, it's up to you to accept my answer or not, and to upvote or downvote it. :)

Comment: @SatoKatsura Well I think it is a bit harsh to say "the question makes even less sense" :) And moreover, if it was the point of the question I would not downvote an answer giving a possible explanation !

Comment: I believe, tilde expansion has been implemented later and wasn't available on the first shells when running ancient Unix. If you want to understand, why `~` expands to $HOME, look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:KB_Terminal_ADM3A.svg)

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Ibelieve it's a little more complicated than that, many of the concepts we take for granted today didn't exist at the time.  Back then MULTICS was the only OS to have a hierarchical filesystem.  The home directory of an user was a central concept, but neither "home" nor "user" meant what they do today.  Home was more akin to the later concept of memory partition on mainframes, while "user" was the owner of said partition, not really a UNIX-like user.  In contrast, a file in a user's home was a lot less interesting.  [References](http://www.multicians.org/features.html#tag18)

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt As for the `~` symbol itself, I don't know specifically when it started to be used in shells, but I wouldn't be surprised to find out it was used to mean "home" even before the concept of shell came to be.  Back then PL/I was in its prime, and it already had a whole menagerie of cabalistic symbols like that. :)

Answer (score 2):

Since your filesystem is hierarchic, you need a way to express the parent-child relationship when moving around.

The simplest way is to use a path separator like `/` (unix) or `\` (windows): on the left, you have the parent and on the right, you have the child.

On linux, the path to your home directory is:

```
/home/username/
```

The path to your `vimrc` is:

```
/home/username/.vimrc
```

where `.vimrc` is a child of `username/`, itself a child of `home/`, itself a child of `/`.

On unix-like systems, `~` is a shortcut for your home directory so `~/.vimrc` is the same as `/home/username/.vimrc`.

Child. Parent. Path separator. Simple.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax needs to be parseable so the shell can understand how to expand what you give it.

Try this on a Linux system:

```
sudo useradd -m .vimrc
vim ~.vimrc
```

Vim will open, but it will be looking at the directory `/home/.vimrc/`.

Is this a pathological case that you would rarely/never see in the real world? Yes. Does it illustrate why the syntax of arguments you pass need to be consistent and use things like path separators? IMO, yes.

If I tell my shell `vim ~dan` then what *should* it do? Should it try to open `/home/dan/`? Or `/home/dan/dan`?

If I tell my shell `vim ~dan/foo` then what should it do? Should it try to open `/home/dan/foo` or `/home/dan/dan/foo`?

What if I keep my billing records in `$HOME/bill/` in files like `0001.txt`, should it work if I say `vim ~bill/0001.txt`? What If I wanted `/home/bill/0001.txt`, how do I say that (in a portable way)? I do not want to parse `/etc/passwd` to find homedirs, assuming the OS even stores the user data in that file.

I see this as being akin to a statement like:

```c
b = a++;
```

It is quite common for programmers to be confused by the behavior of this statement, because until you understand the sequence of events that take place, you might expect that `b` will be assigned a value that is 1 greater than `a`. You might even expect that `a` will not change. But neither of those things are true.

Shells are like any programming language in this way: clarity matters.

Answer (score -1):

What if you have a file called '~.vimrc' ?
I think the only difference is that it avoid ambiguities with filename starting with ~, but I might be wrong.

Comment: If you have a file named `~.vimrc` you'd have to do something like `vim \~.vimrc` or `vim '~.vimrc'` to edit it, to prevent the shell from expanding `~`.  This has to do with the shell, not with Vim.

Comment: To me 'vim ~.vimrc' works fine. I didn't say it had to do with Vim, I could have used the 'more' or the 'head' command as well and the result would be the same.

Comment: For me vim ~.vimrc doesn't work. It opens up a new file. It doesn't hit the .vimrc file. Maybe it's OSX.

Comment: No I mean it "works" if you create such a file. It will not open the '.vimrc' file but the '~.vimrc' file that will be in the directory you are currently.

Comment: my .vimrc file is in the home directory (directory I am in currently) which is where cd ~ will get you and vim ~.vimrc doesn't open it up. It creates a new file

Comment: Let's take it back from the beggining :
I am **not** saying that 'vim ~.filename' would open the '.filename' file in the home directory.
I am saying that 'vim ~.filename' would open the file named '~.filename' in the directory you currently are in.
I was pointing out that if the syntax 'vim ~.filename' was pointing at the file '.filename' in the home directory, you could not name a file '~.filename' because you would not be able to access it then (in the directory that is not your home). Or only with an absolute path.